# Kendo UI - how to get values of all columns headers (name,index,is hidden, etc..)

Tags: datagridview, datagrid, kendo-grid

I would like to ask, how can i get values  of all columns headers (name,index,is hidden, etc..) from datagrid?

I would like to add possibility to save custom user view with predefined order of colums, their visibility, etc..

Could i get it from grid instance (and if  yes,how)?

Or any other suggest how to save and restore custom data grid view?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the column information from the `columns` field. See [**here**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#fields-columns) for more info.

Basically, you can get the columns for any grid by doing something like this:

```
var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
var columns = grid.columns;
```

This gives you an array of columns, thus providing you with the index. The objects themselves contain all the properties of the column including the `field`, `title`, `hidden` and other data.

As an example, to get the title of the first column:

```
var title = columns[0].title;
```

Regarding saving the view, you just have to save this column array and set that as the column option when you initialize the grid again.